# Implementing page break in tabularx environment

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, tabularx

Please consider the following example for better understanding. I would like LaTex to use page breaks within the tabularx environment, so that one part of the contains of `\LongText` will be displayed on the first and the rest on the second page. Maybe there is another useful package for page breaks within long tables or a complete other package for my purpose: a glossary within the main text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{foo}{\tabularx{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}}{\endtabularx}

\newcommand{\LongText}{This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{foo}
Whatever & \LongText \\
Something else & \LongText \LongText
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: install the package ltablex (http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ltablex). It allows a pagebreak for tabularx

Comment: @Herbert: I stored the sty-file in /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/tex/ltablex but. However I get the message "'ltablex.sty' no found."

Comment: did you run `texhash`? However, the file should go into `.../texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/ltablex/`

Comment: @Herbert: Many thanks. I moved everything to the other folder and run texhash. When adding `\usepackage{ltablex}` to the preamble and using `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}` instead of `\begin{foo}` it just works fin. But why isn't possible to use my `foo`-environment as defined?

Comment: that always depends on how an existing environment is defined. In thisa case it is the `endtabularx` which cannot be used inside another definition.

Comment: @Herbert: I found a solution for the problem here: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5274#p27778. However, another problem occurred: I cannot use the `lstlisting`-environment within the `tabularx`-environment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}
Whatever & \LongText \LongText \Something else & \LongText \LongText \Code & \begin{lstlisting} for i=0 do... \end{lstlisting} \\end{tabularx}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most direct package combining `longtable` and `tabularx` (by the same author as those two) is `ltxtable`. However neither it nor `tabu` will do what you want here, which is, I think, split *within* the row of the table. That is rather hard to achieve in TeX and can only really be done in very restricted circumstances. (Consider a general table with many columns, some of which may have images or nested tables), finding a place to break every column at the same place is very hard in general.

If your *real* example is as shown, a two column table with one line entries in the first column, do not use a table layout, use a *list* LaTeX lists can easily achieve that layout and naturally allow page breaks within items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{foo}{\tabularx{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}}{\endtabularx}

\newcommand{\LongText}{This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.}

\lipsum[1-3]
\newenvironment{mylist}[1]% #1 is widest label
     { \list{}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
}{\endlist}



\begin{mylist}{Something else}
\item[Whatever]  \LongText 
\item[Something else] \LongText \LongText
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used `description` beforehand but the disadvantage is that the `description`-environment does not align the text of each item to each other, as for instance the `tabular`- or `tabularx`-environment do.

Comment: description is just one example list the underlying latex `list` construct is very flexible and can easily align the labels on the same line or just use enumerate and `\item[label 1]` but that has different horizontal spacing, but you might like it:-) either way it is vastly easier to customise a list than to break a TeX table mid-row.

Comment: I think `description` is just perfect, as I have non-enumerated items (see edit). Within my paper I have code-snippets. Following the code-snippet I would like to explain some of the commands of the code in a glossary-like environment, such as `description`. I just don't see how to customise the `description`-environment, so that it appears like my `tabularx`-approach.

Comment: code and pic added for list (basically a merger of description and thebibliography from the standard classes)

Comment: How can I set a fix length, instead of `\settowidth\labelwidth{{#1}}`? I know I could write `\begin{my list}{This is the labelwidth which I would like to use throughout my whole document}`, but maybe you have a better solution?

Comment: change `\settowidth\labelwidth{{#1}}%` to `\setlength\labelwidth{#1}%` then the syntax would be `\begin{mylist}{2in}` or perhaps you mean get rid of #1 altogether and have `\setlength\labelwidth{\mylistwidth}%` and have  `\newlength\mylistwidth \setlength\mylistwidth{3in}` in your document preamble so all lists have that fixed parameter

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the `tabu` package which provide the `longtabu` environment which should do what you are after (split tables across multiple pages).

However as David points out, it will not split cells across pages.

Alternatively, another solution would be to use the `parallel` package :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage {lipsum}
\usepackage {calc}
\usepackage {parallel}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}{2cm}{\textwidth-3cm}
   \ParallelLText{test 1}
   \ParallelRText{\lipsum[1-4]}
   \ParallelPar
   \ParallelLText{test 2}
   \ParallelRText{\lipsum[1-4]}
   \ParallelPar
   \ParallelLText{test 2}
   \ParallelRText{\lipsum[1-4]}
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your `tabu`-approach using my example. I implemented `\usepackage{array, xcolor, colortbl, longtable}` in my preamble and added `\begin{tabu}{p{2cm}X}
Test1 & \LongText \Test2 & \LongText \LongText
\end{tabu}` to my example but it did not work.

Comment: I get the "File 'tabu.sty' not found"-message, when implementing `\usepackage{tabu}` into my preamble. The problem is: I don't know how to install packages. I run TeXShop Version 2.47 on Mac OS 10.7.4.

Comment: The message you are getting means that the package is not present in your installation of your TeX distribution. However TeXShop is just an editor so it doesn't give much details about your enviroment. If you are using TeXlive, then `tlmgr install tabu` should do the tick. I do not know the procedure with MacTeX.

Comment: Is it possible that `\usepackage{calc}` is missing in your preamble?

Comment: Quite possibly, I used `lualatex` to compile my example and it loads it automatically. I have modified my post.

Answer (score 0):

For the kinds of tables described in the other answers, the `enumitem` package provides an elegant solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage {lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=10em,style=nextline]
  \item[Whatever] \lipsum[1]
  \item[Something else] \lipsum[1]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```