# How to define a two-column definition environment that breaks across pages

Tags: environments, tabularx, enumitem, ltablex

> Related questions:
>
> - [How to make a table on more than one page by using the table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165793/how-to-make-a-table-on-more-than-one-page-by-using-the-table-environment)
> - [TabularX and \Newenvironment{} with Page Break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328735/tabularx-and-newenvironment-with-page-break)
> - [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width)

I am looking to create an environment which groups definitions for better legibility. Example:

```
\begin{gdefi}
\defi{Ring}{Some long description}
\defi{Homomorphism}{Some long description}
\end{gdefi}
```

The first argument to `defi` should create a column of uniform width (of the longest argument), with the remaining page-width taken up by the second argument.
I would also like for this environment to break across pages for longer groups of definitions.

[image: Illustration]

Implementations I have tried:

1. Create a two-column `ltablex`, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165797/11742), but have been unable to get my document to compile. See below for a non-page-breaking version using `tabularx`.
2. Create a `description` environment which, however, does not use visually separated columns. Using `enumitem`, I was able to tweak this somewhat by manually setting a fixed width for the left column. See below for a version using `enumitem` and a manually-specified width of the left column.

I much prefer approach #1, as it appears to be more more easily extendible. One extension I have in mind is creating different definition commands, each with its own formatting.

Example 1: A **non-page-breaking** version using `tabularx`

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-, DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newif\ifingdefi

\newcommand{\defi}[2]{%
\ifingdefi%
\textbf{#1}:~&#2\\
\else%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{~}L@{}}
\textbf{#1}:~&#2\\%
\end{tabularx}%
\fi
}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{gdefi}{o}
{%
\ingdefitrue%
\tabularx{\textwidth}{@{}l@{~}L@{}}
}
{%
\endtabularx%
\ingdefifalse%
}

\begin{document}

% This environment should break across two pages
\begin{gdefi}
\defi{Def. 1}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 2}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 3}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 4}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 5}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{gdefi}

\end{document}
```

Example 2: An implementation using `enumitem`, which only works when **manually specifying** the width of the first column.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-, DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifingdefi

\newcommand{\defi}[2]{%
\ifingdefi%
\item[#1] #2
\else%
\begin{description}
\item[#1] #2
\end{description}%
\fi
}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{gdefi}{o}
{%
\ingdefitrue%
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
\begin{description}
}{%
\begin{description}[#1]
}
}
{%
\end{description}
\ingdefifalse%
}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{gdefi}[leftmargin=10em,style=nextline]
  \defi{Def. 1}{\lipsum[1]}
  \defi{Definition 2}{\lipsum[1]}
  \defi{Definition 3}{\lipsum[1]}
  \defi{Definition 4}{\lipsum[1]}
  \defi{Definition 5}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{gdefi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `xltabular`? Did you already try with this package?

Comment: Two general comments: Using a `longtable`-like approach (for example with `xltabular`)  will only introduce page breaks inbetween two Definitions, not within the text of one definition. Depending on the length of the corresponding texts, this might lead to quite large white spaces. Depending on the length of the longest term in the first column compared to the other term, there will be huge amounts of white space and a large separation between the term and its definition text.

Comment: Using a `description`-like approach would on the other hand enable page breaks within description texts. Personally, I would stick to a standard `definition` environment only slightly indenting the second an dfollowing lines of the respective definition. To add more visual separation between consecutive items, you could also introduce a small vertical white space between them using the `itemsep` option.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for your helpful comments. `xltabular` indeed works the way I want it to. I will also look into your suggestion of a customized `description` environment, I certainly see the appeal of this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis), the `xltabular` packages works well:

- Auto-fits the size of the left column
- Breaks across pages

Working example for approach #1 in my question:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-, DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newif\ifingdefi

\newcommand{\defi}[2]{%
\ifingdefi%
\textbf{#1}:~&#2\\
\else%
\xltabular{\textwidth}{@{}l@{~}L@{}}
\textbf{#1}:~&#2\\%
\endxltabular
\fi
}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{gdefi}{o}
{%
\ingdefitrue%
\xltabular{\textwidth}{@{}l@{~}L@{}}
}
{%
\endxltabular
\ingdefifalse%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gdefi}
\defi{Def. 1}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 2}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 3}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 4}{\lipsum[1]}
\defi{Definition 5}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{gdefi}

\end{document}
```